# Implementing Fading Slideshow in XCode 6 & iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7, xcode6

I am in the process of developing an app and I'm looking for a way to add a fading slideshow type of element to the app.

I have tried a couple of user suggestions & Answers found through google and Stack Exchange, however a lot of them are very glitchy or don't work for my needs.

I really liked what I saw with a project on `GitHub` called `JBKenBurns` however when I try to integrate it I get the following crash log:

```
2014-12-31 23:36:17.164 Sir John A.[686:60b] -[UIView animateWithImages:transitionDuration:initialDelay:loop:isLandscape:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176ae980
2014-12-31 23:36:17.170 Sir John A.[686:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView animateWithImages:transitionDuration:initialDelay:loop:isLandscape:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176ae980'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x2de14f4b 0x385f16af 0x2de188e7 0x2de171cb 0x2dd664d8 0xe6f81 0x305a212b 0x30651eb3 0x305a212b 0x3060802f 0x30607fb9 0x3058020f 0x2dde01cd 0x2ddddb71 0x2ddddeb3 0x2dd48c27 0x2dd48a0b 0x32a29283 0x305ec049 0xe9f3d 0x38af9ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have tested their Demo and it works fine, but when I implement it based on their instructions, I get that crash log.

I am not set on using this solution, but it would be nice to get it working.

I have also tried adding a `UIImageView` to the `UIViewController` and using the following:

```
self.imagePlaceholder.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], nil];
self.imagePlaceholder.animationDuration = 2.00; //1 second
self.imagePlaceholder.animationRepeatCount = 0; //infinite

[self.imagePlaceholder startAnimating]; //start the animation
```

This solution is looking hopeful, however there images don't fade into each other, it's just a harsh change every second or so.

If anyone can help me either get the JBKenBurns solution working, or help me add a smooth fade to each image, that would be awesome.

Comment: UIImageView.animationImages is used for sprite like animations image cycling. That is why the changes are harsh. Do you need the ken burns effect? or just fading? if it's just fading you need, just use two imageviews and change their alpha values in a UIView animation loop.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now, Rakeshbs. I'm fairly new to iOS development so there are all sorts of things I just don't know yet.

Comment: I hope I have made things clear. try reading the apple documentation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slide show lets try this,  u can also perform the animation by using basic animation and with the help of timer lets say for example, u can do like below when ever u want to stop the animation just invalidate the timer

NOTE:this is just another way to animate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  _imagePlaceholder = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)]; //this is image view
  _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_2.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_3.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_4.jpg"], nil]; //images array to hold images

  [self.view addSubview:_imagePlaceholder];

  //next set up timer to change image at each intervel
  imageIndex = 0; //initially image index will be 0
  _imagePlaceholder.image = [_imagesArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex]; //initially image view contains first image
  _animTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }

 - (void)changeImage {

  //get new index and change it
  if(imageIndex < [_imagesArray count] - 1)
  {
     imageIndex++;
  }
  else
  {
     imageIndex = 0;
  }

  UIImage *nextImage = [_imagesArray objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

  CABasicAnimation *crossFadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
   crossFadeAnimation.duration = 2.0; //this is lesser than timer duration 
  _imagePlaceholder.layer.contents = (id)[nextImage CGImage];
  [_imagePlaceholder.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animateImages"];
  [_imagePlaceholder.layer addAnimation:crossFadeAnimation forKey:@"animateImages"];
  _imagePlaceholder.image = nextImage;
 }
```

Comment: That worked very well! I had to make a few changes in the .h file, but that's obviously to be expected. Is there a way to set the duration of time that the animation takes to complete? Right now the images fade, but the transition only takes about an 8th of a second. I would like to increase that duration to about 1-2 seconds, if possible. EDIT: I was able to increase the duration of the transition by adding "crossfade.duration = 1.0;"

Comment: u can set animation duration, but timer duration  must be greater than animation duration .. any way edited for duration

Answer (score 0):

You can cross fade images with  transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:, by calling setImage in the animation block. Something like this should work,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pics = @[@"img1.JPG", @"img2.JPG", @"img3.JPG", @"img4.JPG", @"img5.JPG", @"img6.JPG", @"img7.JPG"];
    [self changeImage];
}


-(void)changeImage {
    static int counter = 0;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:self.pics[counter]];
                        [self.imageView setImage:img];
                        counter ++;

                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (counter != self.pics.count) {
                            [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
                        }
                    }];
}
```